# How to get request body and response body from Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync in C# to log in DB

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to web api. Can somebody please let me know how to extract Request body and response body from the below.

```
public class TokenValidationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {     
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            HttpStatusCode statusCode;
            string token;
            //determine whether a jwt exists or not
            if (!TryRetrieveToken(request, out token))
            {
                statusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                //allow requests with no token - whether a action method needs an authentication can be set with the claimsauthorization attribute
                return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                   .ContinueWith(task =>
                   {
                       var response = task.Result;
                       // want to save into DB both request and response
                       objSaveRequestResponse.SaveRequestResponse(request, response);
                       return response;
                   });
            }
            return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() => new HttpResponseMessage(statusCode) { });
        }
}
```

Under Login Controller-

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Authenticate(LoginRequest login)
        {
            LoginRequest loginrequest = new LoginRequest { };
            loginrequest.Username = login.Username.ToLower();
            loginrequest.Password = login.Password;

            bool isUsernamePasswordValid = false;

            if (login != null)
                // Can check with DB or config file
                isUsernamePasswordValid = (loginrequest.Username == dataManager.Username && loginrequest.Password == dataManager.Password) ? true : false;
            // if credentials are valid
            if (isUsernamePasswordValid)
            {
                string token = createToken(loginrequest.Username);

                /***********************************/
                //Should save the token with other details like type(access/refresh), issuedDateTime, expiresDateTime, other user details
                /***********************************/

                //return the token
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, token);
            }
            else
            {
                // if credentials are not valid send unauthorized status code in response
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized,"Bad Request Sample");
            }
        }
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.MessageHandlers.Add(new TokenValidationHandler());
```

I tried with request.Content and reponse.Header but No luck.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7X4O.png)

Sample code much appreciated :)

Comment: you want to look in 'response' not 'request'... but... can you show us a little more context? How is this being used? What I mean is... can you show us the code where this is all being used?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Please have a look. I update the code part

Comment: Ok, yes, that's helpful. Now... can you also show us where you are calling this `SendAsync()` method?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston Updated code Please have a look :)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it. But where is the `HttpResponseMessage` handled that is generated in the `SendAsync()` method?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
    HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
    string strContent = requestContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

the same with response.

Update

After the suggestion of @aepot

```
HttpContent requestContent = Request.Content;
string strContent = await responseContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: `await` would look more safe than `.Result`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some trouble following all your code, and I think there is more to it than what you are showing here. But in general, this is how you get the content of an `HttpResponseMessage`:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = //call you method to get the response
string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```